# How can I get an org-mode outline in a 2nd buffer as a dynamic table of contents?

Tags: org-mode, elisp, indirect-buffers

When I edit large documents, I would like to see where I'm at by seeing the outline (with no-content) in a separate buffer. Like when you read a PDF file there is a TOC on the left. (see below)

In org-mode it's possible to expand/collapse outline. But is it possible to have a static outline in the left(or right) in a separate buffer so that when you click on the headings, the other buffer moves to that position?

Kinda like this but for org-mode?
[image]

**[Edit]**
The `clone-indirect-buffer` is very close to what I want. The missing piece of the puzzle is to jump to the same location when clicking a heading/(or any point really).

For this I have tried to write some code: [Move to other cloned buffer to same point? (sync position of indirect buffers) (org-mode)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9536/move-to-other-cloned-buffer-to-same-point-sync-position-of-indirect-buffers)

But it doesn't function if content is collapsed. If that can be made to work, then the clone-inderect-buffer is a complete solution to this.

**[Edit2 Solution]**
The code in the link above and in the answer below combine niceley to solve the jumping back and forth.

```el
;first call 'clone-indirect-buffer'. Then...

;This function works between buffer and it's clone.
(defun my/goto-same-spot-in-other-buffer () 
  "Go to the same location in the other buffer. Useful for when you have cloned indirect buffers"
  (interactive)
  (let ((my/goto-current-point (point)))
       (other-window 1)
       (goto-char my/goto-current-point)
       (when (invisible-p (point))
        (org-reveal)))
)

;This function is a clone-to-buffer jump only:
; It does find the other buffer first thou instead of just jumping to the other 
; window as does the function above.
(defun my/jump-to-point-and-show ()
  "Switch to a cloned buffer's base buffer and move point to the
cursor position in the clone."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (buffer-base-buffer)))
    (unless buf
      (error "You need to be in a cloned buffer!"))
    (let ((pos (point))
          (win (car (get-buffer-window-list buf))))
      (if win
          (select-window win)
        (other-window 1)
        (switch-to-buffer buf))
      (goto-char pos)
      (when (invisible-p (point))
        (show-branches)))))


(global-set-key (kbd "<s-mouse-1>") 'my/goto-same-spot-in-other-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-m") 'my/goto-same-spot-in-other-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-s-mouse-1>") 'my/jump-to-point-and-show)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-m") 'my/jump-to-point-and-show)
```

Comment: Maybe try `C-c C-x b`, or `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer`.

Comment: @SWFlint After a short test, it looks like it does something different from what the OP wants: it copies the current subtree to an indirect buffer. What we'd need would be an `org-sparse-tree-to-indirect-buffer` function, for example, but it does not seem to exist.

Comment: After looking a little further, try something along the lines of [org-panes](http://github.com/knupfer/org-panes)

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning [imenu-list](https://github.com/bmag/imenu-list). It lacks some of the requirements but addresses others.

Comment: org-tree-to-indirect-buffer is awesome.

Comment: Per @blujay's answer below, there's now `org-sidebar` and `org-sidebar-tree`. https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/dbsngi/finally_solving_the_lack_of_a_treeview_navigation/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few options come to mind.  The first two are [`speedbar`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar), which allegedly plays well with `org-mode`, and [`minimap`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MiniMap), although I've not used them so can't vouch for them personally.

What might be the simplest option (and also the most flexible), would be to use an [indirect buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html).

In practice, you would go to the `org` buffer for which you'd like an outline, hit `M-x clone-indirect-buffer` (use `C-u M-x clone-indirect-buffer` if you'd like to control what the clone is called), and then boom, there's another copy of the buffer for you to use.  Put that clone in a window or frame side-by-side with the original buffer and, in the clone, adjust the outline to your tastes.

It doesn't get you the "click on heading in outline" functionality you mentioned, but gets you the spirit of the sidebar.

**Edit:** in response to your comment, here's a simple command that, when invoked from the *buffer clone*, will switch to the *base buffer* and move point to wherever the cursor was in the buffer clone:

```el
(defun jump-to-point-and-show ()
  "Switch to a cloned buffer's base buffer and move point to the
cursor position in the clone."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (buffer-base-buffer)))
    (unless buf
      (error "You need to be in a cloned buffer!"))
    (let ((pos (point))
          (win (car (get-buffer-window-list buf))))
      (if win
          (select-window win)
        (other-window 1)
        (switch-to-buffer buf))
      (goto-char pos)
      (when (invisible-p (point))
        (show-branches)))))
```

Comment: I tried out speedbar/Sr-Speedbar. It is very nice but it only shows the first 2 levels. I asked if it's possible to have more levels here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/speedbar-and-org-mode-only-shows-subheadings-but-not-3rd-level-subheadings             The indirect buffer is a nice option. I wonder if it's possible to somehow move the cursor in the other buffer to the same position as in the cloned buffer..

Comment: I tried to write code that would jump to the same location in the other buffer, but it only works if everything is expanded. If it can be made to work so that it auto-expands, then the clone-buffer is a perfect solution. Post: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9536/move-to-other-cloned-buffer-to-same-point-sync-position-of-indirect-buffers

Comment: Thank you for the snippet of code above. Much appreciated ^_^.

Answer (score 19):

How about: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^*+` <kbd>RET</kbd> (note that there's a space at the end of the regexp).

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this answer, I think this is actually a pretty neat build-in hassle free solution actually. The only quirck is that it doesn't follow you around. I.e it's not obvious in the occur buffer where you are, (highlight the current heading for instance) and it doesn't scroll for long long documents. But for small documents it works.

Comment: I like this simple, built-in solution. If one needs highlighting, use helm-occur instead of occur. An added benefit is to be able to use a single navigation for multiple org file buffers by using multi-occur. Lastly, with occur-edit, one can edit both views, the outline view and the expanded view. In any case, I'm up-voting this.

Comment: Going to upvote this because its awesome, simple and efficient

Comment: So simple. So clever. So hackish. So awesome.

Answer (score 8):

After reading Dan's answer and your solution based on it, I put this together.  It opens a new, narrow, read-only clone to the left of the current buffer, and it binds `<mouse-1>` and `RET` locally in the clone to jump to that position in the base buffer.

```el
(defun my/open-tree-view ()
  "Open a clone of the current buffer to the left, resize it to 30 columns, and bind <mouse-1> to jump to the same position in the base buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((new-buffer-name (concat "<tree>" (buffer-name))))
    ;; Create tree buffer
    (split-window-right 30)
    (if (get-buffer new-buffer-name)
        (switch-to-buffer new-buffer-name)  ; Use existing tree buffer
      ;; Make new tree buffer
      (progn  (clone-indirect-buffer new-buffer-name nil t)
              (switch-to-buffer new-buffer-name)
              (read-only-mode)
              (hide-body)
              (toggle-truncate-lines)

              ;; Do this twice in case the point is in a hidden line
              (dotimes (_ 2 (forward-line 0)))

              ;; Map keys
              (use-local-map (copy-keymap outline-mode-map))
              (local-set-key (kbd "q") 'delete-window)
              (mapc (lambda (key) (local-set-key (kbd key) 'my/jump-to-point-and-show))
                    '("<mouse-1>" "RET"))))))

(defun my/jump-to-point-and-show ()
  "Switch to a cloned buffer's base buffer and move point to the cursor position in the clone."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (buffer-base-buffer)))
    (unless buf
      (error "You need to be in a cloned buffer!"))
    (let ((pos (point))
          (win (car (get-buffer-window-list buf))))
      (if win
          (select-window win)
        (other-window 1)
        (switch-to-buffer buf))
      (goto-char pos)
      (when (invisible-p (point))
        (show-branches)))))
```

This will work with `outline-mode` and `outline-minor-mode`, as well as modes that build on them, such as `org-mode`.  I found [some info](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyBindingDiscussion) about getting the local key maps, but I don't know how to choose which one to copy.  There's also [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferLocalKeys) which has a function to automatically make buffer-specific minor modes for setting buffer-local keys, but that seems out-of-scope for this issue.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. By using `outline-mode-map` instead of `org-mode-map` I managed to make it working for `AUCTeX` with `outline-minor-mode`, which is nice.

Comment: By the way, the `outline-mode`'s function `hide-body` hides everything except headlines.

Comment: @OlegDomanov Thanks for that info!  I improved the code to use the `outline-mode-map` and `hide-body`, and a few other minor improvements.

Answer (score 7):

Finally, this has been implemented in the package [`org-sidebar`](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-sidebar#org-sidebar-tree-command):

[image: org-sidebar-tree demo]

Comment: Hoooray! I have a shakey setup that sometimes just stops working, it is absolutely BRILLIANT if it's a package now!

Comment: I love the helpful `org-sidebar-tree` perspective for maintaining a "big picture" view of lengthy documents.  Thanks for developing!

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar, so I put together [`outline-toc` mode](https://github.com/abingham/outline-toc.el). It should work for org-mode docs.

Answer (score 0):

two low rent suggestions (what i do) from a non-programmer who likes to use aquamacs for text editor:

1. toggle back and forth with in-buffer commands:

## STARTUP: indent (to show the waterfall type outline easier to see as whole)

this is for tab-driven viewing of buffer

and

## +OPTIONS: H:N, where N = =the number of levels you wish to see in html export, which is suggestion #2

see:
https://emacsclub.github.io/html/org_tutorial.html

2. export as html (C-C C-E h h) to see TOC. i can find no one who can easily get the text output of html or text (C-C C-E t a) to indent