# Speedbar and org-mode only shows subheadings, but not 3rd level+ subheadings?

Tags: org-mode, speedbar

I'm toying around with Org-mode and Speedbar/Sr-speedbar.

I like that it shows Task and subtasks. But it doesn't show anything lower, e.g:

```
* Task (shown)
** subtask (shown)
*** Sub-sub task (not shown)
**** sub sub sub task (not shown)
```

Is it possible for it to actually show full depth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be controlled using `org-imenu-depth`.  Speedbar uses IMenu to determine the nodes for expansion.

By default `imenu` only captures two levels deep.  (See [Org Manual - Cooperation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Cooperation.html))

Setting the depth to greater than 2 levels and then initiating a rescan.  This can be done automatically for you by setting `imenu-auto-rescan` to a non-nil value ([GNU Emacs - Imenu](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Imenu.html)).