# Move to other cloned buffer to same point? (sync position of indirect buffers) (org-mode)

Tags: org-mode, indirect-buffers

I like to `clone-indirect-buffer` . But then once in a while, I want to move to the other buffer and go to the same position as in the previous marker.

This is usually the case when I use the indirect buffer as an 'outline' and want to `s-mouse-1` to move the other buffer to the same spot.

I tried to hack together the following:

```
(defun my/goto-same-spot-in-other-buffer () 
  "Go to the same location in the other buffer. Useful for when you have cloned indirect buffers"
  (interactive)
  (let ((my/goto-current-point (point)))
       (other-window 1)
       (goto-char my/goto-current-point)
       (org-reveal))
)
```

But it doesn't work properly if the other buffer's content isn't fully expanded. I.e it doesn't jump into content that is collapsed.

**[edit]**
`org-reveal` did the job. (added to the code above).
Can the above be modified so that it expands sections properly if they are not expanded?

**[edit2]**
This may be of interest to future readers. In [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9530/org-mode-is-it-possible-to-see-only-outline-in-2nd-buffer-like-dynamic-table) post it dissucsses a dynamic TOC where I use the function above as well as another function that first finds the other buffer. You might want to check it out.

Comment: Does calling `(org-reveal)` or `(show-all)` first help? I haven't tried it. [Reference](http://orgmode.org/manual/Global-and-local-cycling.html#Global-and-local-cycling).

Comment: org-reveal did the trick. Thank you. If you post it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`org-mode` global/local cycling documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Global-and-local-cycling.html), the `org-reveal` command should do the trick.

> Reveal context around point, showing the current entry, the following heading and the hierarchy above. Useful for working near a location that has been exposed by a sparse tree command (see Sparse trees) or an agenda command (see Agenda commands). With a prefix argument show, on each level, all sibling headings. With a double prefix argument, also show the entire subtree of the parent.

So call `(org-reveal)` in the elisp.

Comment: Thank you. Btw, this was actually a sub-question of :http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9530/org-mode-is-it-possible-to-see-only-outline-in-2nd-buffer-like-dynamic-table