# Elisp to increase font-size in indirect buffer

Tags: fonts, indirect-buffers

I use org-mode for writing and frequently use a two pane setup, similar to the one described here: [Org-mode 2-pane writing setup using indirect buffers (or display-buffer-alist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47246/org-mode-2-pane-writing-setup-using-indirect-buffers-or-display-buffer-alist). I have an outline on the left, and can open indirect buffers to work on particular subtrees. This function (which I bind to SHIFT-RETURN), opens up subtrees in a right hand pane, and then resize them, so I have a skinnier outline column on the left, and a writing window on the right.

```
    (defun org-tree-open-in-right-window ()
      (interactive)
      (org-tree-to-indirect-buffer)
      (windmove-right)
      (window-resize nil (- (truncate (* 0.7 (frame-width))) (window-width)) t)
    )
```

In addition to opening a subtree in an indirect buffer and changing the window size, I would like to set increase the font size of the right-hand window. That is the skinny, left-hand buffer would have a smaller font size, allowing a view on the whole document, while the right would be larger (in width) *and* larger in font-size, to facilitate writing.

I've tried: `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 150)` but this changes the font size in both. Is there a value I can pass, instead of `nil`, that would restrict this function to just a active window?

Comment: I had hoped `face-map-add-relative` would work but it looks like it affects both the indirect buffer and the original buffer. `text-scale-increase` seems to do that too :-(

Comment: @amitp I just tried @muffinmad's suggestion (Emacs 26.1, Mac OS High Sierra [10.13]) and it seems to work. I just added `(text-scale-increase 2)` to the end of the function in my original post. So far, so good

Comment: Cool! I am not sure why it doesn't work for me. It does increase the font size of the indirect buffer, but it is *also* increasing the font size of the underlying (original) buffer on my system (Emacs 26.2.90, Mac OS Mojave, mituharu-emacs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `text-scale-increase` function:

> `text-scale-increase` is an autoloaded interactive compiled Lisp
>   function in `face-remap.el`.
>
> `(text-scale-increase INC)`
>
> Increase the height of the default face in the current buffer by `INC` steps.
>   If the new height is other than the default, `text-scale-mode` is enabled.
>
> Each step scales the height of the default face by the variable
>   `text-scale-mode-step` (a negative number of steps decreases the
>   height by the same amount).  As a special case, an argument of 0
>   will remove any scaling currently active.

Also see `text-scale-adjust` for interactive use.