# How can i set the same file in org-mode to update only headings in one window and open headings on the other window?

Tags: org-mode, window

I'd like to set a list of headings on one window and write on the other, is is possible?
[image]

Comment: Maybe, that helps: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9530/how-can-i-get-an-org-mode-outline-in-a-2nd-buffer-as-a-dynamic-table-of-contents

Comment: This was helpful. I didn't knew the concept of _clone-indirect-buffer_.